# Difference between Software Design Document and System Design Document

Tags: software-design, system-design, design-documents

I am working on a design document for a module of a web application and while I was researching about the design document, I came across templates with name such as **Software Design Document (SDD)/Software Design Description(SDD), System Design Document (SDD)** and **Technical Design Document (TDD).** What is the difference among these documents?

For my case, I need to design the whole module and it's functions and write the design document for it which could later be adopted by the division for other designs. I am following the Software Design Document/Software Design Description - partly because it's in the IEEE Software Life Cycle and could be basis for the other software team to use in software design.  Can anyone please explain the Design documents and suggest which one would be best to follow for my work?

Answer (score 2):

*I realize you're probably long past needing this answer, but just in case anyone else has this question...*

From my experience, the following names are largely synonymous:

- Software Design Document
- Software Design Description
- Technical Design Document

These are usually used to describe a single feature within an application.

In contrast to those, the "SYSTEM Design Document" describes an entire system, which could be a high-level view of the components within a given application, or all the applications within a given system (e.g. if a midsize company has several applications that interact in some way).

Answer (score 0):

There is the software documentation that describes the requirements and what this software would achieve. At this point the software is not yet created but basically the design, the known technologies to use and also the undecided areas may be indicated. Usally this is made by Senior engineer, Analyst, Manager or a Software Architect ( An engineer with product and design skills )

Another one is the document that describes how the software functions and all technical details that relate to it. Usually this documentations are made by the software developers for other software developers and also for themselves, which serves as a how to use and technical guide for this software. When this software is being developed or even at matintenance, this document is updated to match the changes.

In the industry, the document names are used internally and therefore there is no specific title or some use a more common or simillar sounding titles.